# What is the difference between prepareTestInstance and beforeTestMethod in Spring's TestExecutionListener interface?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit4

So a simple timeline after doing some basic investigation shows something like:

1. instantiate class
2. class setup
3. context injection
4. prepareTestInstance()
5. ....something .....
6. beforeTestMethod()

What happens in step 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think `prepareTestInstance` is called once on created instance of test class. `beforeTestMethod` is called before invocation of every test method of instance of test class.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michail's Answer:
The [related javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) also mentions that for instance dependency injection is handled during this phase whereas `beforeTestMethod`, called before every test method, can be used to set-up fixtures etc.